# parsing JSON file

Tags: iphone, json, ios7

I have JSON file in response.

```
 (
    {
    location =         {
        lat = "23.0429226";
        lng = "72.51406419999999";
    };
    "location_type" = APPROXIMATE;
    viewport =         {
        northeast =             {
            lat = "23.0531899";
            lng = "72.5300716";
        };
        southwest =             {
            lat = "23.0326545";
            lng = "72.4980568";
        };
    };
}
 )
```

To parse lat and long of location i have write this code. but when i am converting that value into float value it is giving me error like this.

> Blockquote

```
  -[__NSArrayI floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdd2d080
 2013-11-21 19:31:15.602 App[3515:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught    exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdd2d080'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0328c5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0300f8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x03329903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0327c90b ___forwarding___ + 1019
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0327c4ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   App                            0x000885d8 __55-[WorkLocationViewController sendLatLongRequestAction:]_block_invoke + 744
6   App                            0x0002901e -[ASIHTTPRequest reportFinished] + 222
7   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0302181f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
8   Foundation                          0x02c64c18 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 285
9   CoreFoundation                      0x032158af __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
10  CoreFoundation                      0x0321523b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
11  CoreFoundation                      0x0323230e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
12  CoreFoundation                      0x03231b33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
13  CoreFoundation                      0x0323194b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
14  GraphicsServices                    0x0462b9d7 GSEventRunModal + 192
15  GraphicsServices                    0x0462b7fe GSEventRun + 104
16  UIKit                               0x01d8294b UIApplicationMain + 1225
17  App                            0x000040fd main + 141
18  libdyld.dylib                       0x037fb725 start + 0
19  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
  )
 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

My code is:

```
 NSDictionary *geo=[res valueForKey:@"geometry"];
    NSDictionary *loc=[geo valueForKey:@"location"];
    NSLog(@"latitiude is%@",[loc valueForKey:@"lat"]);
    NSLog(@"lon is %@",[loc valueForKey:@"lng"]);
    //NSLog(@"float value is%f",[[loc valueForKey:@"lat"] floatValue]);
    NSString *str=[loc valueForKey:@"lat"];
    NSLog(@"string is %@",str);
    NSString *str1=[loc valueForKey:@"lng"];
    workCoordinate.latitude=[str floatValue];

    workCoordinate.longitude=[str1 floatValue];
```

and in log string is print like this:

> ```
>  2013-11-21 19:31:15.599 App[3515:a0b] latitiude is(
> "23.0429226"
>   )
> 2013-11-21 19:31:15.599 App[3515:a0b] lon is (
> "72.51406419999999"
>  )
> 2013-11-21 19:31:15.600 App[3515:a0b] string is (
> "23.0429226"
> ```

Here is JSON which I am getting in response.

```
{
results =     (
            {
        "address_components" =             (
                            {
                "long_name" = "Judges Bunglow Police Chawky";
                "short_name" = "Judges Bunglow Police Chawky";
                types =                     (
                    establishment
                );
            },
                            {
                "long_name" = "Satya Marg";
                "short_name" = "Satya Marg";
                types =                     (
                    route
                );
            },
                            {
                "long_name" = Bodakdev;
                "short_name" = Bodakdev;
                types =                     (
                    sublocality,
                    political
                );
            },
                            {
                "long_name" = Ahmedabad;
                "short_name" = Ahmedabad;
                types =                     (
                    locality,
                    political
                );
            },
                            {
                "long_name" = Ahmedabad;
                "short_name" = Ahmedabad;
                types =                     (
                    "administrative_area_level_2",
                    political
                );
            },
                            {
                "long_name" = GJ;
                "short_name" = GJ;
                types =                     (
                    "administrative_area_level_1",
                    political
                );
            },
                            {
                "long_name" = India;
                "short_name" = IN;
                types =                     (
                    country,
                    political
                );
            },
                            {
                "long_name" = 380015;
                "short_name" = 380015;
                types =                     (
                    "postal_code"
                );
            }
        );
        "formatted_address" = "Judges Bunglow Police Chawky, Satya Marg, Bodakdev, Ahmedabad, GJ 380015, India";
        geometry =             {
            bounds =                 {
                northeast =                     {
                    lat = "23.0369726";
                    lng = "72.51639879999999";
                };
                southwest =                     {
                    lat = "23.03688";
                    lng = "72.5162807";
                };
            };
            location =                 {
                lat = "23.0368868";
                lng = "72.5163184";
            };
            "location_type" = APPROXIMATE;
            viewport =                 {
                northeast =                     {
                    lat = "23.0382752802915";
                    lng = "72.51768873029151";
                };
                southwest =                     {
                    lat = "23.0355773197085";
                    lng = "72.5149907697085";
                };
            };
        };
        "partial_match" = 1;
        types =             (
            police,
            establishment
        );
    }
);
status = OK;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look carefully at your `NSLog` results, you'll see that your line:

```
NSString *str=[loc valueForKey:@"lat"];
NSLog(@"string is %@",str);
```

is returning

```
2013-11-21 19:31:15.600 appname[3515:a0b] string is (
"23.0429226"
 )
```

Rather than what you wanted

```
2013-11-21 19:31:15.600 appnane[3515:a0b] string is "23.0429226"
```

Those parentheses are telling you that `valueForKey` is returning an `NSArray`, not a `NSString`. Two solutions, first, you could just grab the first object from that array:

```
NSArray *latArray=[loc valueForKey:@"lat"];
NSString *str=latArray[0]
NSLog(@"string is %@",str);
```

Alternatively, you might to use `objectForKey` rather than `valueForKey`. Unfortunately, your code snippet does not make it clear what nested array of dictionary objects you logged at the top of your question (e.g. I don't see any reference to `@"geometry"`). But let's say it was `results`. If that was the case, you might do something like:

```
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in results) {
    NSDictionary *location = dictionary[@"location"]; // or [dictionary objectForKey:@"location"];
    NSString *latString = location[@"lat"]; // or [location objectForKey:@"lat"];
    NSString *lngString = location[@"lng"]; // or [location objectForKey:@"lng"];

    CGFloat lat = [latString floatValue];
    CGFloat lng = [lngString floatValue];
}
```

---

In your updated question, you provide a more complete `NSLog` of the resulting object you received from your JSON parser. For example, let's assume that the `NSDictionary` you logged was called `jsonObject`. You could then extract that latitude and longitude via:

```
NSString *status           = jsonObject[@"status"];
NSArray *results           = jsonObject[@"results"];

NSDictionary *result       = results[0];   // let's grab the first result

NSArray *addressComponents = result[@"address_components"];
NSString *formattedAddress = result[@"formatted_address"];
NSDictionary *geometry     = result[@"geometry"];
NSNumber *partialMatch     = result[@"partial_match"];
NSArray *types             = result[@"types"];

NSDictionary *location     = geometry[@"location"];
NSString *latitudeString   = location[@"lat"];
NSString *longitudeString  = location[@"lng"];
CGFloat latitude           = [latitudeString floatValue];
CGFloat longitude          = [longitudeString floatValue];
```

Comment: i have tried first method but its not working i am getting null value... i have post whole JSON file can u pls take a look...

Comment: i have tried your code but i am getting error use of undeclared identifier. jsonObject

Comment: hey rob...can you please do me one favor?? In your answer in second and third  highlighted line it is indicating my application name. By mistake I have also posted it.But now I have remove it.So please can you also remove it from post...Thank you in advance

Comment: @vivek Done, and a moderator has graciously removed the revision history, expunging the app name from there, too.